# The beginning of the year of the set date?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I find the beginning of the year for a set date? That is, let's say I set the date `2018-07-28`, then the result should be  `2018-01-01`. I know that for example in Rails there is such a function as [beginning_of_year](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/beginning_of_year).

Is there anything similar for nodejs?

Or maybe someone already has a similar  for javascript?

Comment: Why don't you just do string concatenation or use setMonth on a copy of the date ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please go through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [getFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) and [construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) a new Date object

```
function beginning_of_year(date) {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0);
}
beginning_of_year(new Date()); // Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Get the year from date and concatenation of string "01-01". Please check below :

```
new Date('2018-07-28').getFullYear()+'-01-01'
```

But if you wants to create Date object for year begging day. Please check below :

```
new Date(new Date('2018-07-28').getFullYear(), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the help of [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) library .

```
var thisYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();    
var start = new Date("1/1/" + thisYear);
var defaultStart = moment(start.valueOf());
```

It is easy way and also a efficient way .